# Is this inductive proof correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

The problem states: If $a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$ and $a_0=2$, $a_1=3$, prove by induction that $a_n=2^n+1$.

My strategy was to assume that $a_n=2^n+1$ indeed is true, then find expressions for both $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n-1}$ and then show that from the assumption $a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$ does follow.

Having checked the base case, let us assume that $a_n=2^n+1$, hence $a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}+1$ and $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+1$. Now let's write the needed equation and see whether we stumble upon some contradiction. $$a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}\Rightarrow 2^{n+1}+1=3\cdot2^n+3-2\cdot2^{n-1}-2$$ which leads to $$2^{n+1}+1=2^{n+1}+1$$ which indeed is true. Would this represent a correct inductive proof?

Comment: I think you need to show explicitly what base case you have checked, because you do not use simple form of induction here.

Comment: @edm Well, both $a_0$ and $a_1$ are given so you can check for any of them. I didn't write the calculation itself since it is trivial.

Comment: What I mean is that you should state that you have checked both $a_0=2^0+1$ and $a_1=2^1+1$, or just keep in mind that you need to check both, because the induction step will not work for proving $a_1=2^1+1$ from $a_0=2^0+1$ (there is no $a_{-1}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "mistake" is that you cannot deduce that the statement holds for $n+1$ from the fact that it holds for $a_n$. This is what you want to show. So, your mistake is exactly in the first sentence "assume that $a_n=2^n+1$, hence..." This "hence" is justified for $n-1$ but is not justified for $n+1$.

Formally, call the statement that you want to prove $P(k)$ (i.e. $P(k)$ states that $a_k=2^k+1$), and then

- Induction hypothesis: $P(k)$ holds for $k\le n$.
- Induction step: Show that $P(n+1)$ holds.

Hence, by the hypothesis $a_{n}=2^n+1$ and $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+1$, which gives $$a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}=3(2^n+1)-2(2^{n-1}+1)=2^{n+1}+1$$

Comment: Alternatively, let your proposition be that $a_n=2^n+1$ **and** $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+1$ for $n\geq 1$, and then proceed as above but assume only that $P(k)$ holds for $k=n$; then you are using simple induction rather than strong induction.

Comment: If I'm using strong induction that means I have to make sure that the induction hypothesis is valid for not only $n$ but also for all $k<n$ ? What is the practical difference in using strong induction generally?

Comment: Actually, strong induction and induction are equivalent, so you do not need to worry about the difference. However, with the suggestion of @DavidK you circumvent this problem in a nice way!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using strong induction generally. The only practical difference I can think of is educational: you might be given an exercise to show something using only induction without strong induction, or you might be proving something in a course that has introduced induction and has not yet introduced strong induction.